# How to fix this circular dependency causing empty object

Tags: javascript, commonjs, apollo-server

Im building the back-end for an app using node and express.

I separated different parts of code in diferent files: for example everything that concerns accessing the database is in the file DBService.js and if I want to perform any action related to my users I have a UserService.js file that does all the app needs with the users, and uses DBService.js to save the users in the DB.

I'm aware I do have some circular dependencies in my code but all worked fine until now. I'm using GraphQL for pretty much everything but I'm adding a normal endpoint to grab a file given it's ID.

I do require the FileService.js in the index.js (entry point to the node app) to serve the file, and this part works good. The problem is that in another file (ZoneService.js) where I also require the FileService.js, it returns an empty object.

I know for a fact that this is the problem because if I remove the require in the index.js file, the problem disappears.

These are the paths that lead to the circular dependencies. The '->' means that the previous Service requires the next.

```
FileService -> ZoneService -> FileService

FileService -> ZoneService -> FileUploadService -> FileService
```

It may look silly but I need this because I thought it was a good move to keep the graphQL type definitions and resolvers of each entity in it's own file.

I will try to explain my reasoning for the first path:

- I want to grab files that are from a certain zone so this function goes into FileService. I then use ZoneService to get the file ID's given the zone ID, then I get the paths from the DB
- ZoneService needs the FileService to resolve the 'files' field in the zone entity

I could just move this function to ZoneService and get the files from there, but would kinda of break all of my logic of separating concerns.

What I would like to know is the best way of fixing this so that it does not happen again, and how can it be avoided.

I would post some code but I'm not sure what so if you think it's necessary let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Edit - Here is some code:

FileService.js

```
//Import services to use in resolvers
const EditService = require("./EditService.js") 
const ZoneService = require("./ZoneService.js") 

//Resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getFileById: (parent, {_id}) => {
      return getFileById(_id)
    },
    getFilesById: (parent, {ids}) => {
      return getFilesById(ids)
    },
    getFilesByZoneId: (parent, {_id}) => {
      return getFilesByZoneId(_id)
    },
  },
  File: {
    editHistory: file => {
      return EditService.getEditsById(file.editHistory)
    },
    fileName: file => {
      return file.path.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    },
    zone: file => {
      return ZoneService.getZoneById(file.zone)
    }
  }
}
```

ZoneService.js

```
//Import services to use in resolvers
const UserService = require("./UserService.js")
const FileService = require("./FileService.js")
const EditService = require("./EditService.js") 
const ErrorService = require("./ErrorService.js") 
const FileUploadService = require("./FileUploadService.js") 

//Resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getZone: (parent, {_id, label}) => {
      return _id ? getZoneById(_id) : getZoneByLabel(label)
    },
    getZones: () => {
      return getZones()
    },
  },
  Zone: {
    author: zone => {
      return UserService.getUserById(zone.author)
    },
    files: zone => {
      if(zone.files && zone.files.length > 0) return FileService.getFilesById(zone.files)
      else return []
    },
    editHistory: zone => {
      return EditService.getEditsById(zone.editHistory)
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    createZone: async (parent, input, { loggedUser }) => {
      return insertZone(input, loggedUser)
    },
    editZone: async (parent, input, { loggedUser }) => {
      return editZone(input, loggedUser)
    },
    removeZone: async (parent, input, { loggedUser }) => {
      return removeZone(input, loggedUser)
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Without at least some (truncated) sample code, or a link to a repo, it's hard to make sense of your description of the dependencies, or how they fit into your schema.

Comment: Is the FileService an object/class?

Comment: https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de

Comment: @DanielRearden I added code samples for the FileService and ZoneService, let me know if you need some more.

Comment: @RandyCasburn FileService is a module (so that makes it like an object right?) that contains the functions and graphQL objects with stuff like resolvers and type definitions. I'm using module.exports to make them avaiable when I require the file.

Comment: @BrunoTavares Aside from my answer below, it also bears pointing out that you could just move your resolvers around to eliminate some of the dependencies between the files. For example, moving the `author` resolver into `UserService` would eliminate the need to import `UserService` into `ZoneService`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of **dos** and **don'ts**:

- **Do** split your schema into smaller modules. For most schemas, it makes sense to split the type definitions and resolvers across multiple files, grouping together related types and Query/Mutation fields. The resolvers and type definitions might be exported from a single file, or the type definitions might reside in a file by themselves (maybe a plain text file with a `.gql` or `.graphql` extension). (Note: Borrowing Apollo's terminology, I'm going to refer to the related type definitions and resolvers as a *module*).
- **Don't** introduce dependencies between these modules. Resolvers should operate independently of one another. There's no need to call one resolver inside another -- and certainly no need to call one module's resolver from inside another module. If there's some shared logic between modules, extract it into a separate function and then import it into both modules.
- **Do** keep your API layer separate from your business logic layer. Keep business logic contained to your data model classes, and keep your resolvers out of these classes. For example, your app should have a `Zone` model, or `ZoneService` or `ZoneRepository` that contains methods like `getZoneById`. This file should *not* contain any resolvers and should instead be imported by your schema modules.
- **Do** use context for dependency injection. Any data models, services, etc. that your resolvers need access to should be injected using context. This means instead of importing these files directly, you'll utilize the context parameter to access the needed resource instead. This makes testing easier, and enforces a unidirectional flow of dependencies.

So, to sum up the above, your project structure might look something like this:

```
services/
  zone-service.js
  file-service.js
schema/
  files/
    typeDefs.gql
    resolvers.js
  zones/
    typeDefs.gql
    resolvers.js
```

And you might initialize your server this way:

```
const FileService = require(...)
const ZoneService = require(...)

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: () => ({
    services: {
      FileService,
      ZoneService,
    }
  })
})
```

Which means your resolver file would not need to import anything, and your resolvers would simply look something like:

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    getFileById: (parent, {_id}, {services: {FileService}}) => {
      return FileService.getFileById(_id)
    },
    getFilesById: (parent, {ids}, {services: {FileService}}) => {
      return FileService.getFilesById(ids)
    },
    getFilesByZoneId: (parent, {_id}, {services: {FileService}}) => {
      return FileService.getFilesByZoneId(_id)
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: It's my first time using GraphQL. I was aware of the context option and I'm using it to access the logged user, but I did not thought of using it to inject the dependencies such as the services, is a great feature! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I should not have mixed up the schema stuff into the business logic. Now that you pointed it out it just makes no sense. I guess I spent too much time finding on how to separate the schema into multiple files and I just did not tought about it too much.

Comment: Just one question regarding your code: context() => ({...}). I don't understand the parentisis around what I think it should be the function code block. Is that the same that using return? What am I missing here?

Comment: @BrunoTavares If you omit the curly brackets in an arrow function, it returns whatever follows the arrow. If the curly brackets are present, what's inside them is treated as statements. Objects also use curly brackets. If we want to return an object using this shorthand syntax, we have to wrap it with parentheses so that what's inside the curly brackets will be treated as an object and not a set of statements. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the link provided! I'm starting to use this new syntax but I need to give it a nice read to learn all the tricks.

Answer (score 0):

For better, you should avoid circular dependencies.
A simple way to do this is separated your module to smaller modules.
As

```
FileService -> CommonService
ZoneService -> CommonService
```

or

```
FileServicePartDependsOnZoneService -> ZoneService
ZoneService -> FileServicePartNotDependsOnZoneService
```

or

```
FileService -> ZoneServicePartNotDependsOnFileService 
ZoneServicePartDependsOnFileService -> FileService
```

*Note that is example. You should naming your module to meaningful and shorter than my example.*

Another way is to merge them together. (But it may be a bad idea)

If you can not avoid circular dependencies. You also can `require` module when you need it instead of `import`.
For example:

```
//FileService.js
let ZoneService

function doSomeThing() {
    if(!ZoneService) {
        ZoneService = require("./ZoneService.js").default
        //or ZoneService = require("./ZoneService.js")
    }
    //using ZoneService
}
```

For reusable, define a function `getZoneService` or something alternative

Comment: I agree with your approach and I tried to figure a way of separating the code into smaller modules but with my current logic I can't find a way of making it happen. I added some code samples, feel free to take a look.

Comment: @BrunoTavares It looks like you just define the `resolvers`, then GraphQL defines the rest of things like `getFilesById` and `getZoneById`. Am I right? I have no experience with GraphQL yet.

Comment: No those are functions I wrote to query the database. The resolvers are parte of GraphQL. The purpose of the GraphQL resolvers is to return the value of a particular field that's not a primitive type. For example Zone has an id property that's a String, that's a primitive type so no problem. However it has an author property that is an User (defined by me) type but GraphQL has no clue, so needs a custom resolver to get the correct value.